# $M$ is weakly dense in $\ell^1(\mathbb N^2)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $\ell^1(\mathbb N^2)$ the dual space of $c_0(\mathbb N^2) = \{x = (x(n, m))_{n, m}~|~\lim_{n + m \to \infty} x(n, m) = 0\}$. Let us define
$$M = \left\{x \in \ell^1(\mathbb N^2)~\bigg|~ x(n, 0) = (n+1) \sum_{m \ge 1} x(n, m) \right\}.$$
I want to show that $M$ is dense in $\ell^1(\mathbb N^2)$ for the weak-$\star$ topology, i.e. for each $y \in \ell^1(\mathbb N^2)$, there exists $(y_p)_p \in M$ such that
$$\forall x \in c_0(\mathbb N^2), \quad \sum_{n, m} x(n, m) y_p(n ,m) \longrightarrow \sum_{n, m} x(n, m) y(n ,m),$$
but I really have no idea how to show that. I've just remarked that for all $z \in M$ and $x \in c_0(\mathbb N^2)$ we have
$$\sum_{n, m} z(n,m)x(n,m) = \sum_{m\ge 1, n} (x(n,m) + (n+1) x(n, 0)) z(n, m),$$
but I do not know if it is useful somewhere.. I really don't know how to explicitly construct $(y_p)_p \subset M$ that converges weakly to $y \in \ell^1(\mathbb N^2)$, does anyone know how to do that ?